# non-capturing group does not work in separator in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have csv file where each row is of this format:

```
(moon_phase)\t(year) (month) (day) (time)
```

for example:

```
new moon\t2011 Jan 04 09:03
first quarter\t2011 Jan 12 11:31
```

I want to use pandas' read_csv() to open the file and come up with a table like this:

```
|moon_phase    |date       |time |
|--------------|-----------|-----|
|new moon      |2011 Jan 04|09:03|
|first quarter |2011 Jan 12|11:31|
```

however, when I use the read_csv's argument `sep` with value `"\t|(?:\d)( )(?:\d)"` to split the line in tab space(to separate moon phase and date) and a regex that uses non-capturing group(to separate the date and time), the result instead is:

```
|New Moon     |NaN|2011 Jan 0| |9:03|
|First Quarter|NaN|2011 Jan 1| |1:31|
```

I want to use the `day` of the month and the `hour` in the match but the separator should only refer to the space between them in separating the date and time. How can this be done in regex?

Comment: yup, I really mean the OR with `|`, since I want to split the line using the `"\t"` or  the space in between the `day` of the month and the `hour` of the time.

Comment: `04` will be matched by using `\d+`. Since you used only one `\d` it's only matching `0`. Same goes for time.

Comment: still,  I got `|new moon|NaN|2011 Jan| |:03`

Comment: Non-capturing doesn't mean non-consuming.  If your group matches `\d`, the digit it matches won't be part of the returned data (since it will be part of the column delimiter).  I suggest you just split on `\t` and read in a single column for the whole datetime, then separately split that into date/time once you have it read in.

Comment: yeah, that would be the next step then, i was just wondering if it is possible to parse the line using the read_csv and regex and get some cleaner and one-liner code, thanks @BrenBarn

Comment: and @noob for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use separator `\t` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then create new columns `Date` and `Time` with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""new moon\t2011 Jan 04 09:03
first quarter\t2011 Jan 12 11:31"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\t", 
                 parse_dates=[1], 
                 header=None, 
                 names=['Text', 'Datetime'] )
print df
            Text            Datetime
0       new moon 2011-01-04 09:03:00
1  first quarter 2011-01-12 11:31:00

df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y %b %d')
df['Time'] = df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')

#if you want drop column Datetime
df = df.drop('Datetime', axis=1)
print df
            Text         Date   Time
0       new moon  2011 Jan 04  09:03
1  first quarter  2011 Jan 12  11:31
```